# Only allow Android apps to be installed on devices with multi-core processors

Tags: android, multiprocessing, cpu, cpu-cores

Is it possible to make an Android application only available/installable on devices with multi-core processors? I know an App can be made for certain Android versions and hardware specifications such as front facing camera.

One way to programmatically solve this is to get the number of cores on a device by calling Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() and then finish the activity if the device doesn't meet my requirements, but this is probably not the correct approach.

So, how do I do this on a Google-approved kind of way?

Comment: Can you please explain the reasons for wanting to require this?

Comment: I want to develop a system for Android that will run on multiple threads, and some jobs have to execute exactly parallel (not the pseudo kind). Thus, I need to ensure that the devices that install the application are actually capable of doing so.
The application includes media handling, recording and editing at the same time. I try to learn multi-thread programming, hence this is just my assumption.. Thank you for taking the time to respond.

Comment: I would be very suprised if you couldn't get this to work on a single core. PCs were all single core until fairly recently

Comment: "and some jobs have to execute exactly parallel" -- then stop developing for Android. Your app requires an OS where you control the thread scheduling, and you don't have that control with Android. Android is welcome to schedule other threads, from other apps' processes, on the cores, or even to turn cores off to save on battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to publish on the google play store, using the android console provided by google, you can exclude devices. This devices  will not be able to install your app. This option is on APK section.
This means that you have to make a list of all devises without multicore processors.

There is also a "supported devices" list that you can edit. Sadly no "cores count" filter.

[image]